# Pandas sort dataframe based on external series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'name': ['a', 'nkjnkj', 'oijhoiuh', 'on', 'lnjjn', 'kmlkm', 'molijoijoij', 'kljkljhlh', 'ghkghgj', 'ihkjhkj']})
```

And I want to sort it by the length of the name, I could do something like:

```
df['len'] = df['name'].str.len()
df.sort_values('len')

 id         name  len
  1            a    1
  4           on    2
  5        lnjjn    5
  6        kmlkm    5
  2       nkjnkj    6
  9      ghkghgj    7
 10      ihkjhkj    7
  3     oijhoiuh    8
  8    kljkljhlh    9
  7  molijoijoij   11
```

But it is possible to do a one-liner? Something like:

```
df.sort_by(df['name'].str.len()) #doesn't exist
```

In other words, can I sort a dataframe based on a series that is not in the dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.iloc[df['name'].str.len().argsort()]
```

Comment: I think it is important to use `iloc` instead of `loc`, as `argsort()` returns positions, not index values.

Answer (score 3):

Just pass a function that returns the values you want to sort on into the `key` argument

```
df.sort_values(by="name", key=lambda col: col.str.len())

   id         name
0   1            a
3   4           on
4   5        lnjjn
5   6        kmlkm
1   2       nkjnkj
8   9      ghkghgj
9  10      ihkjhkj
2   3     oijhoiuh
7   8    kljkljhlh
6   7  molijoijoij
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix your code

```
df.assign(len = df['name'].str.len()).sort_values('len').drop('len',1)
   id         name
0   1            a
3   4           on
4   5        lnjjn
5   6        kmlkm
1   2       nkjnkj
8   9      ghkghgj
9  10      ihkjhkj
2   3     oijhoiuh
7   8    kljkljhlh
6   7  molijoijoij
```